# How to remove duplicate childNode elements within a parent in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, foreach

How do you remove any duplicate childNodes from a parent element so that there is never more than 1 element with the same innerText within the parent? HTML example below of what the before and the intended after is.

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">hello</div>
    <div class="child">hello</div>
    <div class="child">world</div>
    <div class="child">world</div>
</div>
```

**Goal**

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">hello</div>
    <div class="child">world</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you fill out your attempt? There's not much to help you on if we cannot see what you've actually attempted thus far.

Comment: Though, I would not modify an array from within its own `forEach` handler. Imagine what could happen if you remove an element while iterating over it? You can try another array builtin called `filter` which may be more for your use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```js
var children = document.querySelectorAll(".child")
var tmpTexts = []
for (const c of children) {
    if (tmpTexts.includes(c.innerText)) continue
    tmpTexts.push(c.innerText)
    c.parentNode.removeChild(c)
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
        <div class="child">hello</div>
        <div class="child">hello</div>
        <div class="child">world</div>
        <div class="child">world</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s another way of doing it:

```js
const children = document.querySelectorAll('.child');

function filterChildren(text, i, textArray) {
  if ( textArray.indexOf(text) <= textArray.lastIndexOf(text) && textArray.indexOf(text) !== i ) {
    children[i].parentNode.removeChild( children[i] )
  }
}

Array
  .from(children)
  .map( child => child.innerHTML )
  .forEach(filterChildren);
```

```html
<div id="parent">
        <div class="child">hello</div>
        <div class="child">hello</div>
        <div class="child">world</div>
        <div class="child">world</div>
</div>
```